# Сложение строк по дате

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Добрый день. Имеется таблица с 4 столбцами- ActiveTime,Operation,Date,User, в которой на первом месте пишется активное время работы, на втором вид работы, 3 - дата, 4- человек.
Возникла необходимость вывести общее время работы для каждого ее вида  ежедневно. 
Как можно это сделать?

Comment: видимо что то вроде `select Operation, sum(ActiveTime) from tab group by Date`

Comment: @Mike, хм, нет, почему-то не выходит. Выдает is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Пытаюсь понять почему

Comment: ну забыл добавить Operation в group by. добавьте через запятую

Comment: @Mike, нет, суммирование не происходит вообще, просто выводит все столбцы.
p.s. Прошу прощение за долгий ответ

Comment: Значит у вас третье поле это не дата, а дата с временем и конечно для группировки надо сделать из нее только дату, с помощью `date(date)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполните этот запрос:

```
SELECT Operation, sum(ActiveTime), convert(date,Date)
FROM tab
GROUP BY Date, Operation
```